# What are the advantages of a dependency injection framework over classical dependency injection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am struggling to understand the benefits of using a dependency injection framework, in my case CDI in a Jakarta EE context.

I think I see the point of the standard use case for dependency injection - it is often benefitial to "factor out" the concrete instantiation of an instance variable, so that

```
public class Car {
    private Tyre tyre;

    public Car() {
        tyre = new Tyre();
    }
}
```

becomes

```
public class Car {
    private Tyre tyre;

    public Car(Tyre tyre) {
        this.tyre = tyre;
    }
}
```

which has the benefit that now we can insert whatever tyre we like, which is handy for unit tests, for example, as Tyre might be difficult to instantiate.

Now where I am struggling, and I think where many tutorials and questions are a bit thin, is, how you can connect this with a dependency injection framework. Of course, my example would now read (when using CDI)

```
public class Car {
    private Tyre tyre;

    @Inject
    public Car(Tyre tyre) {
        this.tyre = tyre;
    }
}
```

but I don't see why I have gained anything at this stage. I am aware that you could have more than one implementation of the Tyre interface, but then you would have to put another annotation on top of the injection to tell the framework which tyre is inserted... how is this any better than just putting the concrete implementation into the signature?

After summing up my current knowledge and thoughts, my question is basically how a baby example of the following progression could look like:

1. Code without dependency injection and with some problems
2. Same code with dependency injection where some, but not all problems are solved
3. Same code with a dependency injection framework (preferrably CDI) where all problems are solved.

Comment: CDI is just a Java EE implementation of Dependency Injection. Nothing special in contrast with any other DI framework, like Spring. I'm struggling to understand what you are exactly asking.. are you aware of what is Dependency Injection and what it is used for? are you asking the principles of usefulness of the DI? or is your question about *what benefits does CDI have in particular*?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: I am not asking about specifics of CDI, it would just be convenient for me to see explanations given with CDI as I'll be working in CDI. My question is all about the step from manual dependency injection to using a dependency injection framework. What does the framework give me and what is a minimal example to see what it gives me?

Comment: The benefit is exactly "you could have more than one implementation of the Tyre interface".  You don't need any additional annotations because your code around your Car object will insure that only one kind of Tyre is available to be injected, or will otherwise know how to decide which implementation of Tyre to inject.  The point is that the Car class does not need to know about any of that logic.  It just knows it has something to work with that acts like a Tyre.

Comment: I think *benefits* of the DI is quite broad topic and I'd suggest you to do some research instead of asking this here. Also, please rename your title then, as it's misleading - you're asking what are the advantages of CDI over DI - as per your title.

Comment: Case #1 is what you've discussed...hard coding a Tyre implementation, for example, means that you have to change the Car code to change the kind of Tyre used.  Case #2 and Case #3 are the same.  There is no problem that CDI can solve that generic DI can not...CDI is just a specific implementation of DI.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial series that comes at CDI from a slightly different perspective than other such tutorials and I think it may line up to where you're coming from.  Have a look and I hope it helps: https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2019/05/18/a-cdi-primer-part-0/

Comment: @LairdNelson Your tutorial was exactly what I was looking for. Great work. In addition, I like both answers as they helped me to grasp certain aspects of dependency injection and CDI, but I won't choose them as accepted answers because your tutorial would be the true accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with CDI but I can speak about DI frameworks in general in the context of your example.

Suppose you have `SummerTyre` and `WinterTyre`, and you need to use one or the other depending on the `Season`. Without a DI framework, every class that wants to create a `Car` will have to depend on the `Season`, and will have to contain code to create the right `Tyre`s, even though this is essentially an implementation detail of the `Car`.

What DI frameworks let you do is configure this stuff elsewhere (typically in `main` or very close to that), so that all your code just depends on a properly configured injector and nothing else.

In this particular case, you'd probably have a `SeasonalTyreFactory` that is responsible for creating the right kind of `Tyre`. The `Season` is injected into this factory, and the injector is configured to call this factory whenever it needs a `Tyre`. Now any code can request a `Car` without worrying about whether it's got the right set of `Tyre`s!

Answer (score 2):

The only real advantage from the DI perspective is, that you don't have to build the
dependency tree yourself.

Going further in your example, we now use the car:

```
 Tyre myTyre = new Tyre();
 Car theCar = new Car(myTyre);
```

OK, that's not too overwhelming, but imagine a real application with dozens or hundreds
of services, which have their specific dependencies:

```
 ApplicationConfiguration config = new ApplicationConfiguration(...);
 GeneralDatabaseService dbAccess = new GeneralDatabaseService(conf);
 UserRuleService userRules = new UserRuleService(config);
 UserDatabaseService userDb = new UserDatabaseService(config, dbAccess, userRules);
 ...
 // 100 more lines like this
 ...
 ApplicationEntryPoint app = new ApplicationEntryPoint(conf, userDb, ...);
 app.start();
```

In a CDI container, the container does all that scaffolding for you, and it boils down to
simply do:

```
container.select(Car.class).get().drive();
// or
container.select(ApplicationEntryPoint.class).get().start();
```

Apart from that, you have contexts, different scopes for web applications, event handling,
interceptors, and so on...